# CodeIgniter Alias Column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a query that uses Active Record that shows a problem when I execute. The problem is with the count alias name (contagem). When I use the alias on the where clause, I always get a error.

The error is: Unknown column 'contagem' in 'where clause'

How can I solve this problem?

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select($this->produto_categoria_campos . ', count(pc.codigo_produto_categoria) AS contagem');
$this->db->from($this->produto_categoria_tabela . ' pc');
$this->db->group_by('pc.codigo_produto_categoria');
$this->db->where('contagem >', 0);
$this->db->order_by("pc.ordem", "ASC"); 

return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: Can you post the results of `$this->db->last_query()`? This will give you the exact query that's being executed.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting false to $this->db->select as a second parameter to prevent escaping the fields.

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select($this->produto_categoria_campos . ', count(pc.codigo_produto_categoria) AS contagem', FALSE);
$this->db->from($this->produto_categoria_tabela . ' pc');
$this->db->group_by('pc.codigo_produto_categoria');
$this->db->where('contagem >', 0);
$this->db->order_by("pc.ordem", "ASC"); 

return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: Solved with HAVING clause:   $this->db->distinct();
  $this->db->select($this->produto_categoria_campos . ', count(pc.codigo_produto_categoria) AS contagem', FALSE);
     $this->db->from($this->produto_categoria_tabela . ' pc');
  $this->db->join('ec_produto pr', 'pr.codigo_categoria = pc.codigo_produto_categoria');
     $this->db->group_by('pc.codigo_produto_categoria');
     $this->db->having('COUNT(pc.codigo_produto_categoria) > 0'); 
  $this->db->order_by("pc.ordem", "ASC"); 
  return $this->db->get()->result();

Comment: @Marcos: Feel free to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted (for future visitors).